# Taylor series expansions with a small variable parameter and derivatives

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

This might be a stupid question, but I can't seem to understand what's going on with a Taylor expansion I did for a physical problem. I expanded around the small parameter $\Delta x$ and got something like:
$$
f(x)=c\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)h(x))\Delta x.
$$
Now, $\Delta x$ is of course very small, so I can put it inside the derivative. However, in principle, it is also a function of $x$:
$$
\Delta x(x)=tp(x).
$$
Here, the constant $t$ is very small, but $p(x)$ is *not*. So the two functions:
$$
f(x)=ct\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)h(x))p(x),
$$
and
$$
f(x)=c\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)h(x)\Delta x(x))=ct\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)h(x)p(x)),
$$
behave *very* differently. In particular, I am interesting in f(x) in the form of:
$$
f(x)=cg(x)h(x)\left(\frac{d\ln g}{dx}+\frac{d\ln g}{dx}\right),
$$
and the behaviour of the quantity in the parenthesis. So now, if I put $\Delta x$ inside the derivative, I have:
$$
f(x)=cg(x)h(x)\Delta x(x)\left(\frac{d\ln g}{dx}+\frac{d\ln h}{dx}+\frac{d\ln\Delta x}{dx}\right)=ctg(x)h(x)p(x)\left(\frac{d\ln g}{dx}+\frac{d\ln h}{dx}+\frac{d\ln p}{dx}\right).
$$
The additional derivative inside the parenthesis has a huge impact on the behaviour of $f(x)$, as it can, for example, change its sign. But the $p(x)$ outside of the derivative *won't*.

What am I missing here? $\Delta x(x)$ *is* small, so its derivative is also small. It is small because of the $t$ constant, which I suppose is why the logarithmic derivative isn't small. But then, the two forms of $f(x)$ (derivative expanded or not) should be equivalent. What boggles me is the sign change of the whole parenthesis that can occur because of the additional term. The thing is, from a physical point of view, that $\Delta x(x)$ term should be inside, otherwise I have a flux conservation problem.

Comment: A small function does not necessarily have a small derivative (if it oscillates on even finer scales than its amplitude). Perhaps that is what you are missing.

Comment: If that doesn't explain it then we might need more context about your actual setting.

Comment: Since $\Delta x(x)$ is itself a function of $x$, I expanded it as a Taylor series and calculated its derivative. I found that $\Delta x(x+\Delta x)\approx\Delta x(x)$ is a very good approximation. Or maybe it is not the case for all $x$... If that is the case, then the whole Taylor expansion procedure is flawed, right?

Comment: This $\Delta x$ is the size of the perturbation in the whole Taylor expansion?

Comment: Yes that is the case

Comment: I think I need more context to give a better evaluation of what's going on here, because the matter of whether $\Delta x$ is under the derivative or not being impactful is not really very surprising to me. It only stops mattering if $tp'$ can be guaranteed to be small.

Comment: That would be a bit complicated to explain, but the discussion is nonetheless helpful. And I suppose $tp^{\prime}$ being small depends on whether or not the other derivatives are themselves small?